# databases folder is not created

Tags: android-emulator

I created applications having only readable data base.
Earlier they are running fine. 
But now they are giving errors.
The **error** is due to **databases** folder.
As while **copying** data base in application from **Assets** folder,
the **databases** folder, it is not created?
Up till my package folder it gets created.

"/data/data/com.example.test/**databases**/"

So what to do for that?
How to create databases folder in my package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project and restart eclipse. Then problem will be solved.